# UISearchDisplay: searchBar expands automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchresultscontroller

I've implemented `UISearchBarDisplayController` in my project. It works fine with table and search results. Problem start at my search bar's width, it is 300px, and it gets wider in

[image: UISearchBarDisplayController]

as I touch on it, also when I touch cancel Button, It re-sizes itself to 320px instead 300px.

How can I change the size of search bar in `UISearchDisplay` mode? and also fix it back when I returned from that mode. Thanks in advance.

Edit: You can see what i mean when you look at pictures below.

[image: Before]

[image: after]